# Adding JUnit test suite to a Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit5, spring-test, mockmvc

I want to add JUnit test suite to an already up-and-running spring mvc application.

In particular I want to test the Controllers APIs.

Is there a particular procedure you can recommend?

I dont' want to use any spring-boot library/solution.

Thanks in advance.

Giuseppe

Comment: What does the Spring MVC Application do?  Does it just provide a REST API or something more complex?

Comment: It just exposes REST APIs

Answer (score 2):

I usually test the Controllers API with JUnit and Mockito like follow.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MemberApiControllerTest {
    @Mock
    private MemberService memberService;

    @InjectMocks
    private MemberApiController memberApiController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(memberApiController)
            .build();

        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Add Member Test")
    public void addMemberTest() throws Exception {
        //given
        Member member = Member.builder()
            .id("id")
            .password("password")
            .email("email")
            .nick("nick")
            .build();

        //when
        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/member")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(member)));

        //then
        resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk());

        verify(memberService, times(1)).addMember(any(Member.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you suggest me the JUnit and Mockito libraries and related versions to be added to the pom? I'm using Spring 5 and Java 8.